# Server Returned 503 Error on Visual Studio Code MarketPlace

Tags: visual-studio-code, http-status-code-503, marketplace

Are there any problems with the Visual Studio Code Marketplace servers? I've been trying to install packages for 8 hours and I could not. An error appears: Server Returned 503. Or the error is mine or the configuration ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's blog says :

> We are currently impacted by a datacenter outage in South Central US
>   which is causing significant impact across many VSTS services.
>
> We are attempting to mitigate the issue with the dashboards from our
>   side, and working closely with Azure to mitigate the issue
>
> Azure is currently posting updates for this issue at
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/ with the current title of
>   "Multiple Services - South Central US - Mitigating"